# Python dynamic import path

Tags: python, python-import

G'day,

Being a total python noob when it comes to packaging and module organisation..

Given the following (simplified) structure:

```
.
├── bin
│   └── fos.py
└── lib
    └── drac.py
```

And the fact, that when installed, contents of `lib` folder will go somewhere into `/usr/local/share/pyshared` and contents of `bin` folder somewhere in `/usr/bin`, how do I persuade this whole thing to import my modules from `../lib` when in VCS mode and work like it should, i.e. `from modulename.drac import bla` when installed, while keeping imports preferably the same?

Yes, I've read python docs on module organisation and structure, I just can't seem to wrap my head around some best practices. Asking for best practices on SO is stupid, hence this concrete example, which I have on a daily basis more or less.

Is this structure acceptable, if so, how do I organise the imports? If not, what would be the pythonic way to redo it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are bucking the idiom here. What you are describing is similiar to the old c ld_lib paradigm.

There is nothing wrong with a python project sourcing modules out of its own local file tree. Alternatively if your code is really that separate and your `lib` has a well defined API then you should package it separately and import/install it using `ez_install`, `pip`, or a `setup.py`

Generally if the code appears to be evolving together it best to just leave it together. Install it wherever you install your python code (`opt`..etc.) And symbolically link executables into `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: The reason I'm after this kind of structure, is that I generally package stuff for different UNIX distro's. Hence, lib separately, binaries separately. Normal packages to UNIX need to place lib parts generally speaking under `/usr/share`, wherease binaries under `/usr/bin`. I know this might be alien to python module packaging paradigm, but python being _THE_ tool for system administrators should have a way to package contrib "binaries" from the lib code? :) And yes, lib is separate, binary is separate, but packaging 1 python file into a separate UNIX package seems like a huge overkill.

Comment: Think of it in the context of a python library with a command-line interface to use some parts of it :)

Comment: Yeah but once again that paradigm assumes that you are setting up for a linking step. Python has something similiar to a linking step(for finding imported modules) but it works very differently. If you look at the way the `dpkg` for `node` and `npm` work they are similar to what I described in my answer. They deploy the whole shebang into the `lib` or `share` folder then symbolically link the related executables into `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: a lot of that stuff is weird `lsb` stuff that isn't as relevant as it once was. **ducks** flying vegetables.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, that probably makes sense. No vegetables here, just 20 years of legacy mindset :) Thanks man, you gave me a fresh perspective.